# CMS / Server setup to easily host multiple sites

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, hosting, web-hosting, cms

I'm looking for a simple CMS to use for a bunch of micro sites. These are generally sites that are only ever a few pages and are often for friends or simple microsites for work.

What I really want is to setup some nameservers so ns1.quicksitehost.com and ns2.quicksitehost.com for this purpose; and then have a server with apache configured to handle anything pointed at it.

Then the core bit is a simple CMS that can work in this environment. It just needs to be able to create pages, have a WYSIWYG editor (and source editor) and ideally some simple permissions so I can restrict users to individual sites.

Any suggestions on this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the hosting side, I'd recommend Linode or a micro EC2 instance(free tier). Wordpress can handle multiple sites with some plugins. That's probably the easiest one to setup. It's not ideal for static content, but it'll do the trick.

Comment: Thanks; am already using Linode but will give wordpress a go here. Forgot they had a MU version which might well do the trick.